# Why use "remember" keyword in AlertDialog? (Jetpack compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

code reference : https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/material/alertdialog/

```
@Composable
fun AlertDialogSample() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Column {
            val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false)  }

            Button(onClick = {
                openDialog.value = true
            }) {
                Text("Click me")
            }

            if (openDialog.value) {

                AlertDialog(
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        // Dismiss the dialog when the user clicks outside the dialog or on the back
                        // button. If you want to disable that functionality, simply use an empty
                        // onCloseRequest.
                        openDialog.value = false
                    },
                    title = {
                        Text(text = "Dialog Title")
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text("Here is a text ")
                    },
                    confirmButton = {
                        Button(

                            onClick = {
                                openDialog.value = false
                            }) {
                            Text("This is the Confirm Button")
                        }
                    },
                    dismissButton = {
                        Button(

                            onClick = {
                                openDialog.value = false
                            }) {
                            Text("This is the dismiss Button")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have learned about remember and mutableStateOf keyword.
but in this code I think "remember" keyword is not necessary.

If button is clicked, variable openDialog comes true
and if onDismissRequest, variable openDialog comes false

all the functions are controlled passively by code writer.. (not automatically managed by remember keyword)
Then, why use "remember" in this code case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `remember` the composable stores the previous composition value else it will overwrite it every time. Thanks thracian.

ref: https://www.jetpackcompose.app/donut-hole-skipping/

Comment: remember is used to store value from previous composition. Using mutableState which you can consider like a LiveData where compose observes changes of it's value to recompose when value of it has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a situation when the value of `openDialog` is `true` and the parent of `AlertDialogSample` get recomposed for any reason which will trigger a recomposition of `AlertDialogSample` as well. If you do not use `remember`, the value `openDialog` will be set to `false`.

Comment: I have one more question. If use just boolean type instead "remember" and change value, recomposition isn't triggerd? Or recomposition is triggerd but value is set default(false)?

Comment: if you use `val openDialog = mutableStateOf(false)` recomposition will trigger but the value will always be `false`. And if you use `val openDialog = false`, recomposition won't trigger. `remember` has nothing to do with triggering recomposition, it only just hold data, here we are holding `MutableState<Boolean>`; not just `Boolean`

Comment: Here is what I understood. [mutableStateOf] : make value changable and recomposable [remember] : when recomposition is triggerd, previous value will not initialize. and hold value.  is right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thank a lot again. I don't know what time there, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

`remember` is used to store the state of the dialog - whether it is open or not. It helps us to update the UI at run time.

Look at this article on [state management in Jetpack Compose](https://semicolonspace.com/android-jetpack-compose-state/).